# Is there some nice "Nakayama-like" method to test whether a holonomic D module is 0?

Tags: d-modules

A holonomic $D$-module is either the zero module, or one for which the characteristic variety is of the smallest possible dimension. Is there some useful trick to determine whether a holonomic $D$-module is $0$?

Comment: The question is not so clear. Could you give some more detail?